# Given any set $X$ and any $A,B\subseteq X$, is true that for every bijection $f:A\to B$ there exists $\phi\in\text{Sym}(X)$ such that $f={\phi|}_A$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given any (not necessarily finite) set $X$ as well as arbitrary $A,B\subseteq X$, can we always find for every bijection $f:A\to B$ a permutation $\phi\in\text{Sym}(X)$ such that $f={\phi|}_A$ (the restriction of $\phi$ to $A$)?

I know that this is true when $X$ is finite, however what if $X$ is non-finite. Does it still hold then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: take $X=A=\mathbb{N}$, $B=\mathbb{N}\setminus \{ 27 \} $.

Comment: I think I'm having a mental breakdown.

Comment: Really? Why is that?

Comment: @Mark are you asking me to explain the answer or are you asking the user to explain his or her comment?

Comment: @Pedro Asking about his comment. I fully understand your answer. It's very good, I upvoted it.